# Stored Procedure returns NULL value when call using php

Tags: mysql

I have written following code to call stored procedure on server side of button, But it gives me NULL value as output. Can anybody help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
$startDate = $params["startDate"];
$weekInterval = $params["weekIntervals"];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $connectionObj, "CALL Alloc_dashboard( ?, ?, @AllocDetails )" );

mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "ss", $startDate, $weekInterval );
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
$result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT @AllocDetails');
var_dump($result);

list($AllocDetails) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might occur an error in your mysqli_query call.
You should check for an error with

```
var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
```

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Not working. By doing above statement it is returning me NULL. That means no error. And the same query is working for me using simple PHP page. But when I use it in PHPRunners button handle  function It is returning NULL value.

Comment: You said your stored procedure is returning null - now you say it is working but your 3rd party software (PHPRunner) is returning null. So what exactly is the Problem now?